# One-vs-One Classification and Out of Memory Error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, memory-management, classification

I'm trying to classify 5 kinds of data, each has about 10,000 samples.

Using one-vs-one and voting method, I have to run classification for `5(5-1)/2=10` times,

which I have written a loop for that. But I get the massage,

```
Error using svmclassify (line 114)
An error was encountered during classification.
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

What should I do ?

How can I rewrite the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Compress data to reduce memory fragmentation.
2. If possible, break large matrices into several smaller matrices so that less memory is used at any one time.
3. If possible, reduce the size of your data.
4. Add more memory to the system.

With reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html

Comment: I've stored my data in a _cell_ maybe that causes the problem.